# Creating a route with Sinatra to only accept a certain Content-type

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra, content-type, routes

I'm trying to create a route with Sinatra that only accepts POST with an `Content-type: application/json` without success.

My approach is as follows:

```
post '/dogs', :provides => :json do
  # returns here a json response
end
```

Testing with curl, I have seen that `:provides => :json` configures the route to respond with an `Content-Type: application/json`.

That's right because I want also to respond with a JSON message to the POST request but I really need that this route only respond to POST requests with a `Content-Type: application/json` and not, for example, to others (e.g. `Content-Type: application/xml`).

Is there any way in Sinatra to restrict the route to only accept requests with a certain `Content-Type`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Requests do not contain "Content-Type" header, but rather have "Accept". Sinatra should basically only respond to requests with "Accept" containing "application/json". Just to make sure:

```
post '/gods', :provides => :json do
  pass unless request.accept? 'application/json'
...
end
```

Comment: Phil I don't think so, in fact it is a good idea to provide both a `Content-Type` and `Accept` at a POST header HTTP request. For example you could have `Content-Type: application/json` and in the next line of the POST header `Accept: application/json`.

Comment: All in the case of course that you are providing a JSON content in the POST request and waiting a response in JSON format too.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Content-Type" for a request. Read this http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.3

Comment: And there's no option to understand what kind of data was provided in POST except for agreement.

Comment: You are right Phil, in the HTTP 1.1 RFC there is not a `Content-Type` option header for requests. I will try to validate the body content as a valid JSON and send an error if  `Accept` not contains a `application\json`.

Comment: what does "pass" mean? there is no this keyword in Ruby.

Comment: @AlanDert this [is coming](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Passing) from Sinatra

Comment: Content-type actually comes under the Entity section, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html. It is a valid header on a request or response to correct the above. "Accept" is used to define what you as the client as willing to recieve back (you can define more than one). "Content-type" is what the request/response is made up of. Ie, if I'm POSTing json to an endpoint, the content-type needs to be application/json

Answer (score 11):

Read this

http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html

`request.content_type` will tell you

Phil might be right regarding RFC but in reality many things put a content-type in a POST request, therefore it is useful to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

i would think it is something like:

```
pass unless request.accept? == 'application/json'
```